# Creating a Position Grid from Latitude and Longitude Points

Tags: matlab, grid, mapping, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I have two data sets: one of latitude and one of longitude. Both of these datum are 336x264 in size.

I would like to use MATLAB to turn this data into a grid of of position points.

So basically from this:
[image: latlongrid]

to this:

[image: positiongrid]

I don't want to reinvent the wheel here if there is a standardized method of going about this so I figured I should see if the community had any pre-existing resources for this sort of task!

Thank you and best,
Taylor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the mapping toolbox, you can do this with the `projfwd` function:

```
% First, create the projection struct
mstr = defaultm('mercator'); %Or whatever projection you want to use

% Then, project your points
[x,y] = projfwd(mstr,lat,lon);
```

Comment: thank you! I didn't use your exact solution but this got me on the right track! I'll upload solution once its cleaned up.